# Translating SQL sub-query to Peewee ORM

Tags: python, sql, peewee

I have a problem similar to [Translate SQLite query, with subquery, into Peewee statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581826/translate-sqlite-query-with-subquery-into-peewee-statement) and [Can peewee nest SELECT queries such that the outer query selects on an aggregate of the inner query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297971/can-peewee-nest-select-queries-such-that-the-outer-query-selects-on-an-aggregate).

The result I'm trying to generate is: given a `fruit` table with rows of `(type, variety, price)`, find the cheapest variety of each fruit. There are a couple of solutions described at http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ which work:

```
select f.type, f.variety, f.price
from (
   select type, min(price) as minprice
   from fruits group by type
) as x inner join fruits as f on f.type = x.type and f.price = x.minprice;
```

Or:

```
select type, variety, price
from fruits
where price = (select min(price) from fruits as f where f.type = fruits.type);
```

How can I Peewee-ify one or both of these?

Answer (score 5):

Cribbing from http://charlesleifer.com/blog/techniques-for-querying-lists-of-objects-and-determining-the-top-related-item/, I have:

```
subquery = (Fruits
            .select(
                Fruits.type.alias('type'),
                fn.Min(Fruits.price).alias('min'))
            .group_by(Fruits.type)
            .alias('subquery'))

query = (Fruits
         .select()
         .join(subquery, on=(
             (Fruits.price == subquery.c.min) &
             (Fruits.type == subquery.c.type)
        )))
```

This works, but I don't understand everything it's doing. What's going on with `subquery.c` and why is the subquery aliased?

Comment: The reason you alias it is to differentiate it from the other instance of Fruits in the query. The alias indicates that this is a separate *instance* of the fruits table. The ".c" convention allows you to create reference to things like the columns in a correlated subquery.

Comment: maybe I overlooked this in the [docs](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/), but such an example should definitely be listed there. glad I found this answer though.